# Cannot access Map inside a Map using JSTL

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have a `Map` in Java that contains another `Map`, like so:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> myMap = ...
```

I understand this isn't an ideal way to pass data around, but for testing it's easier than fleshing out classes that will only be used to push data to JSTL.

That having been said, we're unable to obtain values in the second-level `Map`:

```
${ myMap[someString1][someString2] != null }
```

It causes a compilation error when loading the page:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /mypage.jsp (line: 142, column: 9) "${ myMap[someString1][someString2] != null }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${ myMap[someString1][someString2] != null }]
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
```

**Strangely enough**, it works fine on the machine running Tomcat 6.0.29, and fails on a machine running 7.0.26.

**Edit:** The webapp is using JSTL-1.2, in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a facepalm answer. I changed the variable names to obfuscate the purpose of the code, thinking it would make things more comprehensible, when it actually masked the problem.

The original code:

```
<c:forEach items="${someobject.items}" var="interface">
    ...
    ${ myMap[interface][someString2] != null }
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Note the variable name for the `forEach` loop - `interface` is of course a reserved Java keyword, but the stack trace didn't do a very good job of drawing attention to this.

Changing the variable name to `interfaze` or anything else fixes the problem.